# Unix script to run multiple PLSQL queries in on connection and store each queries' output in different variable

Tags: oracle, unix, plsql, sqlplus

I have written a unix script for PLSQL query where I am making connections separately for each query and storing the query result in variables. I want to improve the code efficiency by making the connection once only and storing the result of each query in different variables.
Here is my working code

[image: attached code snippet]

```
var1=`sqlplus -s $user/$password <<EOF @$query1 $value exit EOF`
var2=`sqlplus -s $user/$password <<EOF @$query2 $value exit EOF`
var3=`sqlplus -s $user/$password <<EOF @$query3 $value exit EOF`
```

I am expecting a solution like

```
    sqlplus EOF
    var1=query1
    var2=query2
    var3=query3
    EOF
```

Please help me with correct syntax

Comment: You probably can't do that. Have you checked the documentation for `sqlplus` to see if you can pass it multiple queries and somehow obtain multiple responses?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can get more than one variable per connection, but not with a simple backquote stdout redirect. You'll need to mark the values in some way so that you can separate them out afterwards. There are a number of ways to do that.

One way is to spool them to different files. Simply add "`spool a`", "`spool b`", "`spool c`" or whatever you want to name them at the top of each sql file. Run the script, then back in shell, read the three "`a.lst`" "`b.lst`" `c.lst`" files into three variables.

Another way is to add a dummy column that identifies the query to each sql file:

```
SELECT 'query_a' dummy,actualvalue FROM ...
```

You can spool that or capture stdout:

```
res=`sqlplus /nolog 2>&1 <<END
  @$query1 $value  
  @$query2 $value
  @$query3 $value
  exit
END
`
val1=`echo "$res" | grep query_a | awk '{print $2}'`
val2=`echo "$res" | grep query_b | awk '{print $2}'`
val3=`echo "$res" | grep query_c | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Another way is to run your queries inside a PL/SQL block and assign the output, with markers, to SQL*Plus bind variables that you can print:

```
res=`sqlplus /nolog 2>&1 <<END
  var value_1 varchar2(20)
  var value_2 varchar2(20)
  var value_3 varchar2(20)
  BEGIN
    SELECT 'value_a='||myvalue INTO :value_1 FROM ...;  
    SELECT 'value_b='||myvalue INTO :value_2 FROM ...;
    SELECT 'value_c='||myvalue INTO :value_3 FROM ...;
  END;
  /
  set heading off
  print value_1
  print value_2
  print value_3
  exit
END
`

val1=`echo "$res" | grep value_a | cut -d'=' -f2`
val2=`echo "$res" | grep value_b | cut -d'=' -f2`
val3=`echo "$res" | grep value_c | cut -d'=' -f2`
```

These are just a few ways. I'm sure others can think of more.